# Separating Global memory accesses and local memory accesses in an ARM ELF

Tags: arm, local, elf, global

I have an ARM ELF. I want to filter out local memory accesses from global memory accesses for each function. I can do it programmatically by decoding each load/store instruction to find out what address it refers to. Is there any easier way of doing it?

Comment: define what you mean by local vs global accesses?  you talking local vs global variables?

Comment: locals can be optimized away to literally nothing if they are part of dead code, unoptimized they are on the stack so pretty easy to find, globals are in .data or .bss so pretty easy to find in the elf file...decoding the load/store instructions wont get you there you have to simulate the instruction set and how are you going to know if a load/store is related to a variable in the high level language or not?

Comment: By locals I mean those variables/memory locations that are present on a function/thread stack and by global accesses I mean those variables/memory locations that are shared by functions/threads in a program

Comment: I understand that I can obtain all the global variables by looking them in .bss or .data section. But it will give me all the globals in a program. I need to obtain only those global memory locations that are used by a particular function/thread.

Comment: You would have to simulate and follow all the nesting and passing of pointers, etc.  And then you would have to figure out how to isolate functions.  I have seen gcc use the same code segment for two functions, not a tail optimization but both functions were functionally identical it produced one the other did a branch into the other.

Comment: So dont care what a paper says on some topic, you cant simply decode the load/store instructions and figure anything useful out about the higher level language or even local stacks, etc.  Nor can you isolate functions to see if they touch a stack (by disassembling).  Simulation will get you a part of the way but somewhere in the middle, very tight controls on the compile will get you closer, but all the way.

Comment: The point being you cannot do it by disassembling load/store instructions because that 1) wont work. 2) in this case something simpler than something that wont work, wont work either.

Comment: I guess in architectures such as x86_64 where the locals of a function are accessed using rbp (base pointer), it is possible to distinguish global memory accesses from the local ones (e.g mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax) But in ARM which is a load store architecture, its going to be tricky ....anyway I am looking  into it.

Comment: a frame pointer is a compile time option, and not always assumed to be there (x86, arm or otherwise), you can have a frame pointer with arm as well.  Still doesnt isolate high level language accesses from compiler/code overhead accesses.  doesnt put dead code back in, etc.  will have the same problem with any instruction set.

Comment: x86 is very much variable instruction length so a disassembler is a significantly more difficult task, full of failure opportunities and very easy to defeat intentionally or accidentally.  compiled code is easier to disassemble as there wont be any accidental (or intentional) traps, but still you have to dissassemble everything cant just be looking for loads and stores (same is technically true for arm as thumb and arm mixed or thumb, thumb2, and arm mixed make for variable instruction length and what you are doing anyway you have to disassemble everything).

Comment: all instruction sets are going to have the problem of finding the high level language function boundaries when looking at the machine code.

Comment: the bottom line here is independent of instruction set if you are trying to do this generically for any program, it is a fail, not 100% possible even if you were to hand analyze as a human.  If you want to put very very specific constraints on the compiler version and settings, you cant get 100% but you can get a lot closer, but may still need an emulator which then opens up more traps to fall into.